# Intensity of the colors in the current color (for beginners)

Tags: actionscript-3

There is a task : to change a color MovieClip (clip) so that when you click on a button (btn1, btn2, btn3 ...) with other colors ( red, blue, green, yellow) , was added to the color intensity MovieClip selected color.

MovieClip for use :

```
private var ct: ColorTransform = new ColorTransform ();
private var color: uint;
```

To use the buttons :

```
yellowBtn.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, yellowButtonClick); 
private function yellowButtonClick (e: MouseEvent): void {   color =    0xFFFF00;   setColor (); }
```

Function to set the color :

```
private function setColor (): void {   ct.color =  color;   clip.transform.colorTransform = ct; }
```

I do not understand how you can be added directly to a color intensity of the current. Thought may make sense to convert HEX RGB, and then just get on with RGB ...

```
r = color >> 16 & 0xFFFF00;
g = color >> 8 & 0xFFFF00;
b = color & 0xFFFF00;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To begin with a look at the description of the ColorTransform. There is clearly a Intensity.

```
var ct:ColorTransform = new ColorTransform(1, 1, 1, 1, rOffset, gOffset, bOffset, 0);
```

Comment: `This applies to the current color of a display object or not?`

Comment: `first color set using

    var color:Number = Math.random( ) * 0xF95A61;
    var ct:ColorTransform = new ColorTransform( );
    ct.color = color;

And then already changing its intensity. For example, the color in the library is yellow , and all action with the color produced is over yellow.

    var rOffset:Number = clip.transform.colorTransform.redOffset;
    var gOffset:Number = clip.transform.colorTransform.greenOffset;
    var bOffset:Number = clip.transform.colorTransform.blueOffset;
`